# What changes when appending a relative element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've noticed that when I append a relative element to another element something changes and  the subsequent elements are always added to the right of the previous, so it seems that at some point during the append a left value is changed but I can't figure out which?

A small example would be adding 5 spans to a div and placing them all at left:10 and top:10

To have them on top of each other you'd have to take the amount of items added from the left value. i.e once you add 5 items the following item's left will be 10-5*10

Are there any other ways to find out what the left value of the appended item should be so it goes on top of the previous?

Here's some code examples and a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x2mc8/1/)

Html

```
<div id="container"></div>
<span id="el" class="drag"></span>
```

Javascript

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   var element=$('#el').clone();
   $(element).html(i);
   $(element).attr("id","el"+i);

   $('#container').append(element);
   $(element).css({                  
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        position: 'relative',
        marginRight: 0
    });
}
$('.drag').draggable();
```

Update:

I'm not so much looking for a "fix" as I have it working I'd just like to know if there's a value change in the element once a relative element is appended or removed from it

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you need to use absolute positioning rather than relative positioning.

Comment: Seems like you might want `absolute` with the parent set to `relative`.

Comment: What should be the result? Can you make a small sketch of it?

Comment: `position:relative` has two meaning. First, it signifies that their children element will be positionned relatively to it. The second meaning is the one that affects you here. It means that the element will be positionned relatively to its ignitial position. So, if you set a `10px left` it means that the span will be 10 px on the right of the place it would have taken if you haven't set anything. If you are looking to go in the `10px 5*10px` way, you then set your span as `absolute` and their container to `relative`, regarding the first definition I've given and James comment.

Comment: I've updated the question. Absolute is the right way to do it but not what I'm looking for, just looking for some enlightening re: appending relative elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not so much looking for a "fix" as I have it working I'd just like
>   to know if there's a value change in the element once a relative
>   element is appended or removed from it

The css from an element doesn't change if you add another element to it if that is what you are asking. The behaviour you see is caused by the browser fitting the elements like you asked it to. Since 'left: 10; top: 10;' is already occupied, it tries to fit it somewhere near there. That said, there is nothing stopping you from counting the amount of elements that a certain element contains. (`$('#container').children().length`), or the offset of an element on the page (the actual position; `$('#el4').offset().left` or `$('#container .drag:last-child').offset().left`). Because relative elements position themselves always relative to other elements, this is most likely not going to help you much.

---

> To have them on top of each other you'd have to take the amount of
>   items added from the left value. i.e once you add 5 items the
>   following item's left will be 10-5*10
>
> Are there any other ways to find out what the left value of the
>   appended item should be so it goes on top of the previous?

If you want the elements to actually stack, you probably need to alter the code so they are properly displayed next to each other, then use `margin-left` to move the left border into the element, so they are displayed over each other. `.draggable()` will calculate the position from there, and as long as you don't alter the DOM after you've made the elements draggable you should be fine.

Example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmW8T/2/

```
for(var i=0;i<80;i++)
{
    var element=$('#el').clone();
    $(element).html(i);
    $(element).attr("id","el"+i);
    //$element.addClass('element');
    $('#container').append(element);
}
$('#el').remove();
$('.drag').draggable();
```

With CSS:

```
.drag {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    background: #FEEFEF;

    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

#container {
    padding-left: 25px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you use `position:relative` the element still occupies its space on the page, affecting the other elements. That's why each 10px left property you add, pushes the next element to the left also.
As already pointed out on the comments, using `position:absolute` solves the issue, as the "absolute" value makes the element float out from the page, and it doesn't occupies its space anymore, also it does not affect other elements.

Comment: Can you explain "affecting the other elements"? Is there some offset that changes or something? That's what I'm wanting to know

Comment: The element with "position:relative" still works as a normal element. It occupies its space on the page, meaning that every element that comes after it, will be placed next to it, not above it. Its the HTML default behaviour for any element. Try creating two inputs in sequence, one will appear next to the other, not above it. But the point is that with "position: relative" you can set "left", "top", "right", or "bottom" offsets from where it was supposed to be. But still, the space it was supposed to occupie remains there.

Comment: "position:absolute", on the other hand, floats the element off the page. Try creating two inputs in sequence with "position:absolute" and "left:0". One will appear above the other because they don't belong to the same level on the page scope.